# How to get image url from server response in swift 4 using Alamofire framework

Tags: swift

I beginner in iOS, how to parse an image url from server response and display image in image view. Before to display an image i used a variable of type String to store  server url and convert to string url to of type NSURL, But now bunch of images coming from JSON response.

[image]

In above image which contain only one element, like this a 20 to 30 elements are coming from server. I want access that profile element and photo (Key).

[image]

In the above image just neglect that search loop code.

[image]

In the above image I am Mapping to cell of tableview.

Can anyone suggest me how to parse this `JSON` response using `Alamofire Framework` and i used a `Alamofire Image Framework` also to parse an image.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Don't show screenshot, copy/paste code or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

After converting it to NSUrl, You need to download that image from server , for that you can use NSData or other libraries like https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage or https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher.

Comment: Thank you for reply